# Почему не вводятся данные в масив char (память выделялась динамически) , язык С

Tags: c

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему не вводятся данные (символы) в массив `char` (память под него выделялась динамически). С массивом `int` все работает. Массив `int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <conio.h>   
#include <locale.h>  
#include <malloc.h>  
#include <process.h>

void big_init(int**,int);

void main(){  
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");  
    int *a;  
    int n;  
    system("cls");  
    puts("Введите длинну массива");  
    scanf_s("%d",&n);  
    big_init(&a,n);  
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){  
        puts("Заполните массив");  
        scanf_s("%d",a+i);  
    }  
    printf(" [%d ] \n",*(a+0));  
}    

void big_init(int**arr,int sz){  
    *  arr=(int  * )calloc(sz,sizeof(int));  
    if(arr==0){  
        puts("Ошибка");  
    }  
}
```

А массив `char` не работает:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h>  
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>


void new_arr (char **,int);

void main(){  
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"Russian");  
    int n;  
    char *arr;  
    puts("Введите длинну массива:");  
    scanf_s("%d",&n);  

    new_arr(&arr,n);  
    gets(arr);  // эту строчку компилятор пропускает  
    puts(arr);  //и эту строчку  пропускает тоже  
}  
void new_arr(char **arr,int n ){  
    *  arr=(char * )calloc(n,sizeof(char));  
    if(arr==NULL){  
        puts("Ошибка");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Вы смотрели на то, как выглядит код в вашем вопросе?

Comment: "gets(arr); // эту строчку компилятор пропускает" - кстати, напрасно пропускает :)

Comment: вы как пишете? #include stdio.h> ? странно, что другое работало..
поправили после подсказки? Так отписались бы хоть.
"..При этом в коде имеется ошибка: проверка результата выполнения calloc должна выглядеть иначе:.." Для alexolut:
почему? Указателю можно задать нулевое значение, присвоив ему 0. Например:
p = 0 ;
Для обозначения числа 0 при работе с указателями во многих заголовочных файлах языка Си определяется макроконстанта NULL. Считается, что если указатель содержит такое значение, то он не готов к работе.
Ps И если есть ошибка в коде - как он может "успешно" работать? :) Извините.

Comment: библиотеки были подключены правильно. с массивом char  не работает в отличии от массива int

Comment: Для Сергей Леоновец: если это правильно #include stdio.h> а было у вас вначале именно так, то это не с. Или вы нас мистифицируете.

Comment: Оставляйте комментарии в соответствующих секциях, к соответствующему вопросу, и для упоминания пользователя используйте символ `@` перед ником. Про `NULL` я Вас совершенно не понял. `calloc` возвращает результат в `*arr`, поэтому `*arr` и нужно проверять, а не `arr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

99% за то, что вы вводите число и нажимаете Enter. При считывании `scanf` выбирает из потока цифры, встречает `\n`, понимает, что чсло кончилось... оставляет `\n` в потоке. Затем `gets` читает `\n`, и полагает, что введена пустая строка...

Так что если предполагается раздельный ввод числа и строки - то рекомендовал бы после считывания строки игнорировать все последующие символы до `\n` включительно.

Comment: Спасибо помогли!!!!  после ввода числа очистил строку  fflush(stdin);

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код [вполне успешно](http://rextester.com/EQVCI33325) работает в `Visual C`. Вероятно проблема в том, как Вы задаете входные данные. Нужно передавать число и сразу же за ним строку (без пробелов и переводов строки), например: `20hello`.

При этом в коде имеется ошибка: проверка результата выполнения `calloc` должна выглядеть иначе:

```
if(*arr==NULL){ // Добавлено разыменование
```

P.S. Вопрос о разумности использования `gets` оставлю за рамками текущего ответа.

Comment: У меня на Visual Studio 2010, не работает именно с массивом char, с int идет без проблем.

Comment: @СергейЛеоновец понятие 'не работает' не информативно. Распишите в вопросе подробнее, что именно происходит. Что подается на вход и т.д.

Comment: Ошибок студия не выдает. В случае с char массивом :через консоль задаем размерность массива, он инициализируется,  заполняется нулями (смотрел через точки остановы) и после стандартная фраза перед выходом из консоли "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу....." т.е. команды в gets и puts в main  он пропускает

Comment: @СергейЛеоновец я показал Вам пример ввода и дал ссылку на онлайн-компилятор. Всё работает. Поэтому остается в силе вопрос: `Что и как Вы подаете на ввод?`. В пошаговом выполнении при отладке курсор должен останавливаться и на `gets`, и на `puts`. То, что Вы не видите результатов на консоли может быть следствием неправильного ввода.